# how to winsorize series based on year in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[this my dataset called t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fCxd.jpg)

```
year    roe
33  1987    0.114370
34  1988    0.141086
35  1989    0.144621
36  1990    0.135348
37  1991    0.076381
```

I tried to winsorize roe based on each year, but all values became NaN, like this:

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize
grouped=t.groupby('year')
t['roe_w']=grouped['roe'].apply(winsorize,limits=[0.01,0.01])
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZt0O.jpg)

```
t.roe_w.head()
33    NaN
34    NaN
35    NaN
36    NaN
37    NaN
Name: roe_w, dtype: object
```

I tried to define a new function to apply but got the same result again. And I cannot directly winsorize groupby object

if I do this, I don't know how to add the results to the original dataframe...

```
t.groupby('year').roe.apply(winsorize,limits=[0.01,0.01])
Out[57]: 
year
1965    [0.14415390338, 0.117462079171, 0.128658847171...
1966    [0.150060493701, nan, 0.12508992087, 0.1676523...
1967    [0.169752998571, nan, 0.128173648284, 0.117999...
1968    [0.120201520849, nan, 0.162525114893, 0.137850...
1969    [0.112350791976, 0.114198765054, 0.18420285951...
1970    [0.0939597998646, 0.181250926338, 0.0782947478...
1971    [0.0790746582545, 0.184407887041, 0.0254160825...
1972    [0.0930312074128, 0.201296434986, 0.0800409603...
```

I tried this function, it worked well, but the results are slightly different from stata. So I still have to use scipy's winsorize to get the same results as in stata.

```
def winsorize_series(se):  
    q = se.quantile([0.01, 0.99])  
    if isinstance(q, pd.Series) and len(q) == 2:  
        se[se < q.iloc[0]] = q.iloc[0]  
        se[se > q.iloc[1]] = q.iloc[1]  
    return se
```

HELP! HELP! QAQ

Comment: Hey, have you managed to find the answer Vevina? I'm in the same boat - I have already asked a question on the stack but no one seems to be able to help.

Comment: Hi I used the function "winsorize_series" posted in my question. Although the results looked slightly different from that of Stata, it did well.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have it sorted as well - different method.